# Is there a way to connect to a Bluetooth Low Energy device under Android 5 exposing the public static address?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop

**Background**:
I use a BLE device (`peer') that communicates with my Android app without pairing -- the peer device advertises and android connects to it.  During this connection, the Android device transmits its own Bluetooth address (this is part of each connection).  Under Android 4.4 this used to be its public static (i.e. Bluetooth-MAC) address, under Android 5 (at least with my Nexus 9) this is a private random address.

**The Problem**:
The peer device checks the supplied address of the Android device and allows only devices with known address to connect.  When using a newly generated random address for each new connection, this does not work.

This post
[Android 5 static bluetooth MAC address for BLE advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602672/android-5-static-bluetooth-mac-address-for-ble-advertising)
indicates, that at least for advertising it's not possible to disable this privacy feature.  **My question**: Does anyone know, how to disable this privacy feature and let Android transmit its `true' public address on connection?

Comment: You can check the latest update on post [Android 5 static bluetooth MAC address for BLE advertising ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602672/android-5-static-bluetooth-mac-address-for-ble-advertising).