# Android 5 BLE connect with random static VS resolvable private address

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

**Setup:**
BLE peripheral is embedded device with "Just Works" association model and Android phone is BLE central. BLE peripheral advertise with public device address.

**Observation:**
BLE central as Android 4.4.2 on Samsung S5 mini connects with BLE peripheral by public device address.
BLE central as Android 5.1.1 on Samsung S6 connects with random static address.
BLE central as Android 5 on Nexus/LG phones connects with random resolvable private address

**Question:**
Is there a way to change type of address that android try to connect with BLE peripheral from random resolvable private address to random static OR public device address?

This is similar questions as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171193/is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-a-bluetooth-low-energy-device-under-android-5-expos) but no answer there.

Comment: Are you sure the Android is using random static addresses? That seems so unlikely.

Comment: Yes for Samsung S6 with android 5.1.1 it is random static address.