# Detect nearby presence of Android Device via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Is there any smart way for an App installed on 2 devices close to each other to recognize themselves via Bluetooth without asking anything to the user ? 
Note that I'm not talking about transferring data or any other operation, I just want to know (for sure) that this particular device is close to me (for example a simple shared ID or hardware address would be far enough).

**Important :** it has to work from Android 4.4 to Android 6, so it means that :

1. We cannot rely on BluetoothLeAdvertiser because it's only from API 21.
2. We cannot rely on BluetoothAdapter Mac Address recognition because [it is now broken and randomized](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id) from API 23.

Answer (score 0):

Android API 21 added the Periphal Bluetooth Low Energy Profile so that an Android device may act as a Beacon or provide a fully working Gatt Server.

The following list provides devices that are hardware-compatible (which is quite limiting) -> https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html

So I am afraid there is now way of doing this in LE in KitKat.

And since the list of devices is quite small and lots of enabld-LE device back from Jelly Bean and KitKat (like Samsung Galaxy Note 3) are not capable of advertising on a hardware level, this would not work well for you.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Indeed it looks like we have to forget using Bluetooth LE. The other way to do would be to discover any Bluetooth peripheral (the classical way, without LE)... that was possible until Android M breaks it : is there any trick to circumvent the fact that API 23 randomizes the phone's advertised MacAddress ?

Comment: @JBA that is curious. I thought that the randomization of the Mac Address is only in LE and since API 21 as explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975466/android-bluetooth-le-mac-address-randomization . I believe that is not the case in Bluetooth Classic or else it would break the purpouse of pairing of Classic Bluetooth while in LE there is no required pairing :)

Comment: You're right, this is curious... there is maybe some subtle details I didn't noticed as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id) is not absolutely clear about BT classic / BT LE... I will implement some tests on my devices and come back later here with the results...

Comment: I just tried with Marshmallow, BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() returns the constant 02:00:00:00:00:00 as mentioned in the doc... So indeed it becomes impossible to get the Android-M phone Bluetooth Mac address...

Comment: A user-centric workaround is explained [here](https://www.socketmobile.com/about-us/media-center/blog/socket-talk/2016/02/10/the-case-of-the-missing-bluetooth-address) ... and some others rely on reflection like in this [so answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34016529/1720332) - it looks like this latter is actually working.

Comment: Excellent ! But still strange that the MAC Address would change for BT Classic. How classic pairing works then ? Really streange...