# Multiple MAC addresses appears for the same device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, mac-address

I implemented a Bluetooth advertiser and a receiver using Android. At the receiver I wanted to find whether unique MAC addresses are available for each and every advertisers. For the test I used a HTC mobile as the receiver and a Samsung j5 mobile. I found there are many MAC addresses appear at the receiver.

here is my code for receiver,

```
   @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);

        BluetoothDevice testDevice = result.getDevice();
        String address = testDevice.getAddress();
        outlbl.setText(address);
    }
```

so I tested the surrounding with a custom app and found this,

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxx4e.png)

for the same data there are many MAC addresses from the same device.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the devices randomize their mac addresses. These may address it further

[Randomize Mac Address Bluetooth LE Broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708067/randomize-mac-address-bluetooth-le-broadcast)

[Does MAC ID broadcasted in Eddystone Beacon change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136261/does-mac-id-broadcasted-in-eddystone-beacon-change/42139586#42139586)