# Advertising Bluetooth MAC address of phone through webpage

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I'm fairly new to web Bluetooth and am trying find a way to advertise the unique bluetooth MAC address of an android phone using web Bluetooth (I am trying to read the bluetooth MAC address using a Raspberry Pi Zero W).

I have tried the web demo at https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/demos/bluetooth-printer/ - running on an android phone and reading using the Zero W. But the MAC address read by the RPi Zero W changes each time I press "Pair" on the webpage.

I saw this post about IOS ([Randomize Mac Address in BLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60504133/randomize-mac-address-in-ble)), so I'm guessing android also randomizes the (BLE) MAC address.

Is it possible to advertise the phones unique MAC address - or anything else that can uniquely identify the phone - through web Bluetooth on an android phone? (Preferably through BLE for speed). If yes, how can that be done?

Also would this work in a similar way on IOS?

Thank you

Comment: I also see that there are two other roles, besides "Peripheral" and "Central", called "Observer" and "Broadcaster". 

Is it possible for the webserver to act as a broadcaster? i.e. just to send out a unique ID/MAC for the phone where the webpage is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Bluetooth API currently allows websites, running in the Central role, to connect to remote GATT Servers over a BLE connection. In other words, this API discovers and communicates with devices over Bluetooth using the Generic Attribute Profile (GATT).

What you're looking for is an API that lets you simulate BLE peripherals. You may want to try the [BLE Peripheral Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral) android app that is used as a companion to the Web Bluetooth API to ease experiments by providing another device to connect to.

Or you can use [nRF Connect for Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en&gl=US) Android app, a powerful generic tool that allows you to scan, advertise and explore your Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices and communicate with them.

Comment: It would be preferred if the phone doesn't need to download/install additional software

Would it be possible to send a phones unique ID/MAC to a GATT server? For example: a GATT server is running on an RPi --> the webpage on the phone sends a unique ID/MAC to the GATT server when it is in range.

Thank you

Comment: It is not possible for the web app running on the phone to discover the phone's unique ID/MAC address however it is possible for it to generate a unique ID, store it in local storage, and transmit it to the GATT server so that the device can identify the phone when  it connects again in the future. It would help if you explained why you wanted to share the MAC address with the GATT server. There may be another approach to solving that problem.

Comment: Thank you, 
Basically I need a way to identify phones (android and IOS) at different locations. For example: a person goes to a location and taps their phone on something (e.g. bring it near a RPi), then a unique ID and the current date/time is logged. It is preferred that the user not have to install anything extra. For android I've tried to detect a unique ID (using bluepy) with "Nearby Share" enabled on the phone but nothing shows up

Comment: It seems like Web NFC could be a great fit your use case.
Example: A person goes to a location and taps their phone on an NFC tag, then thanks to Web NFC, the NFC tag serial number is read and logged through the web app. See https://web.dev/nfc/ for more information.

Comment: web.dev/nfc looks interesting, I will have a look at it.
Thank you everyone for your help, I will mark this as the accepted answer.